# Is there a disorder that causes one to feel heat from an inanimate object?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, psychiatry, physiology, psychology

We just met a woman that feels heat (literally, hot enough for her to say she was burned) from inanimate objects. She says it is mainly the floors and chairs in her home, and she is unable to walk in certain places or sit in certain places if they are hot at the time. Not everything is hot all the time, and sometimes she has no problem with chairs or floors, but will suddenly get burned as she walks across the floor, or sits in her chair.

She's becoming very anxious over this, and I'm wondering if there is a physical or mental disorder that could explain it. Thank you.